# Как браузер обрабатывает SVG <use> теги при сборке страницы?

Tags: svg, производительность, svg-спрайт

Предыстория. Предположим имеется веб страница на которой все SVG элементы запакованы в спрайт и положены возле закрывающегося тега `<body>` По необходимости они вызываются через `<use>` в `<html>` разметке документа.

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon" />
</svg>
```

При создании страницы, согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/use) все теги  клонируют унаследованный элемент (в моем случаи который храниться в спрайте), и в этом месте у меня возникло недопонимание по поводу производительности. Если элемент клонируется, то он раздувает DOM дерево? Видит ли google бот эти полотна svg кода при парсинге страницы при индексации ? Что будет производительнее - подключить 5 иконок через тег `<use>` или же предположим подключить их через `<div>` с свойством `background-image="../my-icon.svg"`  (там запрос происходит один раз, а потом отдается из кэша браузера)

Answer (score -1):

svg для google бота такая же картинка как и png, причем в плане SEO и скорости сайта она даже лучше чем png. СВГ код он не индексирует, читает только svg-заголовок - берет его вместо alt текста обычной картинки. В основном свг подключают через div, use лично я не встречал.

Comment: **В основном свг подключают через div, use лично я не встречал**.  А стоит ли отвечать на вопрос, в котором, судя по ответу плохо разбираетесь? На всякий случай минус не мой, я их вообще очень редко ставлю А насчет использования use в svg, так это практически, в каждом втором вопросе-ответе есть. Даже целый раздел посвящен этому  [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82)